# Input string not in correct format on 1 system

Tags: c#

This is a strange one, on most of my systems this code works fine:

```
var separator = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
DA = Math.Round(double.Parse(M.Groups[1].Value.Replace('.', separator))).ToString();
```

It brings back a digit like for example: 12.6754645644 so we just round up the M.Groups[1].Value to **12** for example, although it works on most systems in 1 it is throwing an error:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>      at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)

The strange thing is, it works on most systems I have tested on, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? (I suspect you trying to hack something like `double.Parse("1.234", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Hi, yeah i'm just rounding the digit up to 1 for example and cut off everything after the "."